# When is the best time to use Mat-Dialog

Tags: angular

I am building a very large app for my company. I am using SQL Server for the database, C# .Net Core for the server and Angular 8 for the front end.

I have dozens of pages in this app. Some more complicated than others. I am building this currently based on their existing design which was done in Filemaker(Apple product). The current app has a ton of popup modals similar to a dialog to display a variety of information when a button is pushed. One page has 30 of these buttons on it. Within those modals can be a small amount of data or a long page of information from multiple tables.

I am trying to re-create their existing system (to minimize learning a new system) but with much better software. However, it feels like this whole modal usage is getting really out of hand. Also the information becomes very complex to update as I have modals with tables that need to have full CRUD operations on them. I originally thought to do a modal within a modal, but this is getting ridiculous. Besides getting these tables to display the updated data without reloading the page is simply giving me a headache. I can get several techniques to work once and then something prevents them from working a second time.

I have been using Mat-Dialog to open a modal and load in a component to mimic what they currently have, but I feel like I'm going about it the wrong way. Perhaps I should just go to the component instead, update the data and then go back to the first page?

I guess what it comes down to, is should I be using Mat-Dialog this way? When is the right time to actually use it? Is there a better way to handle massive updates or new data?

If any of this doesn't make sense please let me know.

Any input is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: the right time to use a modal is subjective and depends heavily on context. Any design that meets the needs of the users can be considered "correct"

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate reusable component for mat-dialog.
You need to pass some details in calling every popup, along with you can pass some conditional things. If you want to show table in popup, you can pass table:true or if not you can pass table:false. similarly many things you can do just using a single popup component.

```
    openDialog(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
      width: '250px',
      data: {name: this.name, table: true}
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('The dialog was closed');
      this.animal = result;
    });
  }

}

  <li>
  <button mat-raised-button (click)="openDialog()">open dialog</button>
  </li>
  <li *ngIf="table">
    You chose: <i>{{your data}}</i>
  </li>
```

I have used the similar way for dozens of popups in my application.

Comment: Thanks for the the response! Do you have any problems with the UI updating after closing the dialog? I am also using GraphQL with Apollo

Comment: No I didn't face any issues in updating in UI. Not used GraphQL in my Application